# What is the best way to back up a database encrypted with Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-encryption

I'm using the package `betterapp\LaravelDbEncrypter` to encrypt some data in the DB.

If something goes wrong and I lose the access to the server, even if I have a back up of the database in a different place, I won't be able to access that data anymore.

What could be the best approach to save a back up of the database, so it can be recovered even if Laravel's app key is not the same anymore?

I was thinking about decrypting all values and saving the backup within a 7z with password. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

The package uses Larave's [Encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/master/encryption) feature which relies on the value of your `APP_KEY` in your `.env` file.

To be able to restore your database backup you need the same `APP_KEY`-value in your second, restored application.

I would advice to keep a copy of the `APP_KEY` in a safe location. Like a password manager like 1Password or LastPass.

Decrypting all encrypted values in your database seems to me like a lot of work. As you would probably would have to encrypt them again in your restored app.